# Is it a correct behavior of SO to allow marking a question duplicate of a future post?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925633/appending-a-text-file-inside-a-custom-directory) on StackOverflow was marked duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926707/proper-way-of-waiting-until-a-file-is-created). (Before going further, I want to make it clear that I'm not talking about this post in particular, I'm talking about the behavior of SO in general).

Now, we all know that *marking duplicate* is quite an old and useful process in SO. But, the post I'm referring to, was marked duplicate of another post *which was posted later (in future) than the "duplicate" post*.

This particular question referred here is kind of a trivial question, and similar questions have been answered many times on SO I believe. But, in general, when a post is marked duplicate, it shows in the header that "**This question already has an answer here...**". Which looks like the OP didn't try to find relevant posts in SO before posting his own. This is true a lot of times for duplicate questions, but obviously, `one cannot search future posts`! Maybe the OP did enough research, but could not find a suitable post that answered his query. Later, someone posted a similar question and got good answers. But, that does not make the first question duplicate of the second one, does it?

So, my question is, what the community thinks about this SO behavior

1. This behavior is just perfect
2. SO should not allow marking a post duplicate of a future (posted later) post
3. There should be option while marking duplicate, that says something like "This questions has relevant answer(s) here..." (*not "already"*)
4. Other ideas?

Comment: Yes it's allowed to mark a newer (better) Q&A as duplicate. It makes the OP look nothing, as you suppose.

Comment: I know it is "allowed", my example shows exactly the same thing. I'm asking if standard duplicate text "question *already* has an answer.." is right.

Comment: If this is only about wording maybe better ask at ELU.se ... :)

Comment: I'd venture a guess that 99.99% of all duplicates are the newer question.  For the common case, the text using 'already' clarifies to the person asking the question what happened.

Comment: I see even this question being marked duplicate :) And it's going back to the "wording" only!

Comment: Your premise is false: Jon Skeet *can* search future posts.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski lol :) yes he can, I trust his search method :)